# On the dimensionality of the Hilbert space for a central potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

So, we have that for particles in a central potential, the wavefunction can be expressed as:
$$\psi(\mathbf{x})=R(r)Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$$

Explanation (not crucial in the question):

> $Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$ are spherical harmonics (functions associated to the eigenvalues of the orbital angular momentum $\mathbf{L}^2$ and one of the components of $\mathbf{L}$). And $u(r)=rR(r)$ satisfy the following form Schrödinger equation: $$Eu(r)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{d^2u(r)}{dr^2}+\left[V(r)+\frac{l(l+1)\hbar^2}{2\mu r^2}\right]u(r)$$ Source: Weinberg, S. (2015). *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781316276105

My question is:

> In this case what is the dimensionality of the space $\mathcal{H}$ of the solutions?

On the one hand, the solutions in the particular case of the Hydrogen atom are products of Laguerre polynomials and Spherical Harmonics, which can be identified using the quantum numbers $n, l, m$, thus the states are linear combinations of $\varphi^m_{n,l}$, a countable set:$$\psi=\sum_{n,l,m}C_{n,l,m}\varphi^m_{n,l}$$

On the other hand, as functions, the $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ can be thought of as linear combinations of the position basis $\delta(\mathbf{x})$, since there are as many $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ as there are $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$, this set is uncountable: $$\psi=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d\mathbf{x}\:C(\mathbf{x})\delta(\mathbf{x})$$

This baffles me since on the one hand we have that the basis is countable ($\aleph_0$-dimensional) and on the other the basis appears to be uncountable ($\aleph_1$-dimensional*). Clearly they can't both be right.

*assuming that the continuum hypothesis holds.

Comment: These things are tricky. There are other questions which deal with the (somewhat related) topic of what the position "basis" really means. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441503/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hilbert space of harmonic oscillator: Countable vs uncountable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64869/)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I did a quick search before asking but it didn't occur to me to search specifically for Harmonic Oscillator related questions.

Comment: @DanYand I was going to write an answer but I found myself almost quoting you verbatim - perhaps you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment and acknowledged by the OP, 
the answer has already been explained in this post:

[Hilbert space of harmonic oscillator: Countable vs uncountable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64869)

I'll just list a few key points to 
help put the answer in perspective:

- Quantum field theory, and all of its various useful approximations
  (like nonrelativistic single-particle quantum mechanics),
  always uses a **separable** Hilbert space. By definition,
  a separable Hilbert space has a *countable* basis.
- All infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces
  are isomorphic to each other — meaning
  that as far as their abstract Hilbert-space structure is concerned,
  they are all the same.
  This unique Hilbert space can be constructed
  in many different-looking ways. Different
  constructions are useful in different models.
  One construction, especially useful
  in nonrelativistic single-particle quantum mechanics,
  involves representing
  vectors in the Hilbert space as 
  functions $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto\mathbb{C}$,
  and then the inner product of $\psi$ with itself is
  represented by the integral of $|\psi|^2$.
  This is the construction used in the OP's question.
- If $|\psi\rangle$ is any vector in a Hilbert space,
  the inner product of $|\psi\rangle$ with itself
  is a well-defined (finite) real number.
  Therefore, the function $\exp(i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x})$
  does not represent any vector in 
  the Hilbert space, even though it can be useful
  as a computational device.
  The same comment applies to
  the "function" $\delta(\mathbf{x})$.
  This resolves the paradox that was described in the question.
  The Hilbert space has a *countable* basis that
  suffices for constructing all other 
  *vectors in the Hilbert space.*
- The inner product of $|\psi\rangle$
  with itself is not zero unless $|\psi\rangle$ itself is zero.
  In particular, the inner product of the difference $|a\rangle-|b\rangle$
  is not zero unless $|a\rangle=|b\rangle$.
  Therefore, two functions that differ from each other
  only on a subset $\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ of measure zero
  both represent the *same* vector in the Hilbert space.
  This is nicely explained in tparker's answer to
  the question linked above.

Comment: Then this makes me wonder, is there such a thing as a "position basis"? Because if $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ is not a state vector, then it obviously can't form a basis for the Hilbert space. Then what do we understand when we use the "$\ket{\mathbf{x}}$"?

Comment: @SalvadorVillarreal  Strictly speaking, the answer is no, there is no such thing as a "position basis," and the notation $|x\rangle$ is only a shortcut. It is still convenient, and people often write $\langle x|f\rangle$ as an abbreviation for $f(x)$. Similarly, the position operator $X$ (and momentum operator $P$) doesn't have any eigenvectors, at least not in the Hilbert space. It has a continuous **spectrum**, but no eigenvalues. When books talk about "eigenvectors of $X$", they are using a _shortcut_. Good books should at least mention this, like pp 101-102 in Griffiths' _Intro to QM_.